# Doubt about meaning of a subcategory "being closed under extensions"

Tags: category-theory

I am not even sure of the definition of extension. I have read that given a morphism $f:X\to Y$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$, a extension along a monomorphism $i:X\hookrightarrow Z$ is a morphism $\overline{f}:Z\to Y$ such that $f=\overline{f}\circ i$.

If this definition is correct, when do we say that a subcategory is closed under extensions? Do I need the morphism $f:X\to Y$ to be in the subcategory or just X?

Comment: Where did you see the terminology?

Comment: Here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension. I thought that what I needed was the first notion, the one labeled as "extension of morphisms", but know I have seen that it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a quite different and unrelated use of the term "extension." Generally the ambient category is an [abelian category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) (although generalizations are possible), and in this context an [**extension**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension#extension_of_an_object_by_another_object) of an object $B$ by an object $A$ is an object $C$ fitting into a [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence)

$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} C \xrightarrow{g} B \to 0$$

meaning that $f$ is a monomorphism, $g$ is an epimorphism, and $\text{ker}(g) = \text{im}(f)$ (see the link for definitions).

A subcategory is then said to be **closed under extensions** if whenever $A$ and $B$ lie in that subcategory, then so does any extension $C$. For example, inside the abelian category of abelian groups, the following (full) subcategories are closed under extensions (some of these are nice little exercises):

- Finite abelian groups
- Finitely generated abelian groups
- Torsion abelian groups
- Torsion-free abelian groups
- Divisible abelian groups

However, the following subcategories are *not* closed under extensions:

- Cyclic abelian groups
- $p$-torsion abelian groups

Comment: I am new here, do I have to do something once my question gets a good answer?

Comment: @Jorge: you can upvote the answer and accept it by clicking the little check mark. Thanks!